# Possible to modify/prune learned trees in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

It is possible to access tree parameters in sklearn with

```
tree.tree_.children_left
tree.tree_.children_right
tree.tree_.threshold
tree.tree_.feature
```

and so on

However, trying to write to these variables raises a not writable exception

Is there any way to modify the learned tree, or bypass the AttributeError not writable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attributes are both arrays  of int that can not be overwritten. You can still modify the elements of these arrays. That will not lighten the data.

```
children_left : array of int, shape [node_count]
    children_left[i] holds the node id of the left child of node i.
    For leaves, children_left[i] == TREE_LEAF. Otherwise,
    children_left[i] > i. This child handles the case where
    X[:, feature[i]] <= threshold[i].

children_right : array of int, shape [node_count]
    children_right[i] holds the node id of the right child of node i.
    For leaves, children_right[i] == TREE_LEAF. Otherwise,
    children_right[i] > i. This child handles the case where
    X[:, feature[i]] > threshold[i].

feature : array of int, shape [node_count]
    feature[i] holds the feature to split on, for the internal node i.

threshold : array of double, shape [node_count]
    threshold[i] holds the threshold for the internal node i.
```

To prune a DecisionTree by the number of observations in nodes, I use this function. You need to know that the TREE_LEAF constant is equal to -1.

```
def prune(decisiontree, min_samples_leaf = 1):
    if decisiontree.min_samples_leaf >= min_samples_leaf:
        raise Exception('Tree already more pruned')
    else:
        decisiontree.min_samples_leaf = min_samples_leaf
        tree = decisiontree.tree_
        for i in range(tree.node_count):
            n_samples = tree.n_node_samples[i]
            if n_samples <= min_samples_leaf:
                tree.children_left[i]=-1
                tree.children_right[i]=-1
```

Here is an example which produces graphviz output before and after:

```
[from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor as DTR
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz as export

bunch = load_diabetes()
data = bunch.data
target = bunch.target

dtr = DTR(max_depth = 4)
dtr.fit(data,target)

export(decision_tree=dtr.tree_, out_file='before.dot')
prune(dtr, min_samples_leaf = 100)
export(decision_tree=dtr.tree_, out_file='after.dot')][1]
```